# $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{x-a}{y}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> The normal to a curve at any point on it $P(x,y)$ cuts the $x$-axis at $x=a$. Therefore, $P(x,y)$ satisfies the differential equation given by $\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{x-a}{y}=0$.

Why is this true? Can anyone provide any explanation or reasoning?

Comment: Hint: consider a line with slope $m$ and $x-\text{intercept}=a$. What is its expression?

Answer (score 0):

Equation of normal  at point $(x,y)$ on the curve of $P(x,y)$ is
$$Y-y = -\dfrac{dx}{dy}(X-x)$$

Since the normal cuts the $x$ axis at $(a, 0)$, plugin $X=a$, $Y=0$ and rearrange.

Answer (score 0):

The slope of normal at any point to the curve is $m  = -\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

Then the equation of the normal is $y-0 = -\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}(x-a) \implies \frac{dy}{dx} +\frac{x-a}{y}=0$